# How do I cast the elements referred by a slice without heap allocation?

Tags: rust, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

Let's suppose there's an array of parameters that need to be used in SQL query. Each parameter must be a `&dyn ToSql`,which is implemented already for `&str`.

The need arises to use the object both as `&dyn ToSql` and as `&str`, like in the example down below, where it needs to implement `Display` in order to be printed out.

```rust
let params = ["a", "b"];

// this works but allocates
// let tx_params = &params
//             .iter()
//             .map(|p| p as &(dyn ToSql + Sync))
//             .collect::<Vec<_>>();

// this is ideal, doesn't allocate on the heap, but doesn't work
params.map(|p| p as &(dyn ToSql + Sync));

// this has to compile, so can't just crate `params` as [&(dyn ToSql + Sync)] initially
println!("Could not insert {}", params);
```

Error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: ToSql` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:14:20
   |
14 |     params.map(|p| p as &(dyn ToSql + Sync));
   |                    ^ the trait `ToSql` is not implemented for `str`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a str as ToSql>
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn ToSql + Sync`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:14:20
   |
14 |     params.map(|p| p as &(dyn ToSql + Sync));
   |                    ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `str`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn ToSql + Sync`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

The trait `ToSql` isn't implemented for `str`, but it is for `&str`, however we borrow checked won't let us borrow `p` here, even though we're not doing anything with the data, except cast it as a new type.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0eac60e677e0641a2aad2710b8c417cd)

Comment: I see you've already got a more specific answer, but just for the future — for a question like this it would be useful to tell us the exact type of the function you're trying to pass the iterator to — so we know whether it actually requires `&dyn ToSql` exactly or another type providing ToSql somehow would do. That will affect the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Caesar's take on this, however you actually can do that without heap allocations.

You can use [`<[T; N]>::each_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.each_ref) for that (this method converts `&[T; N]` to `[&T; N]`):

```rust
params.each_ref().map(|p| p as &(dyn ToSql + Sync));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f6085180963c5375dc7900c62edb9b2e).

Answer (score 1):

I fought this a month ago and my general recommendation is: Don't bother. The actual query is so much heavier than an allocation.

The situation is a bit confusing, because you need an `&ToSql`, but `ToSql` [is implemented](https://docs.rs/postgres-types/latest/postgres_types/trait.ToSql.html#impl-ToSql-for-%26%27a%20str) for `&str`, so you need two arrays: One `[&str]`, and one `[&ToSql]`, whose elements reference `&str`s - so the contenst of `[&ToSql]` are double references. I don't see an easy way of achieving that without allocating. (`let params: [&&str; 2] = params.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>().try_into().unwrap();` works and the allocation will likely be optimized out. Nighly or unsafe ways exist, see @ChayimFriedman's answer.)

In this case, you can work around either by initially declaring:

```
let params = [&"a", &"b"];
```

by using an iterator, not an array:

```rust
let iter = params.iter().map(|p| p as &(dyn ToSql + Sync));
client.query_raw("select * from foo where id in ?", iter);
```

In my case, I wasn't able to do anything like this because I was using execute, not query, and `execute_raw` exists only on `tokio-postgres`, but not on `postgres`. So beware of these kinds of pitfalls.